# apt-get update gives 404 error on all main ubuntu mirrors

Tags: apt, updates, 19.04

Trying to update my ubuntu 19-04 disco apt sources.list and I have this error message since a few days:

[image: sudo apt-get update]

apparently all main mirrors for ubuntu disco are gone from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/
even google's cache still references the urls I have in my apt sources.list

[image: google search]

but I get the same 404 not found from the browser (obviously) so does anyone experienced the same issue recently? I can't imagine that the urls for main repositories for ubuntu 19-04 disco were just updated...?

Comment: disco (19.04) is past EOL (End Of Life), so what you are getting is expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: not really because I was wondering why I couldn't update my OS facing this 404 error from the default ubuntu mirrors, it seems strange to me that it's handled this way when the EOL comes...

Comment: How in the world is this "off-topic"? This is the topic. It's Ubuntu, and `apt` is broken because it just spits out 404s instead of telling the user that they're EOL and it's time to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @Doug Smythies for pointing that ubuntu 19-04 disco is now EOL (End Of Life) so when this happens, one should upgrade to the latest "10" version with command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/01/ubuntu-19-04-end-of-life

Comment: Closed as "off-topic" and took forever to find, but this is the right answer when your problem doesn't have to do with added PPAs. None of the other 404 answers mention this.